# Why is there a warning saying "Immutable value..."?

Tags: swift, dictionary, warnings

I keep getting a warning saying "Immutable value 'key' was never used" in Xcode when I run my program in Swift, specifically at my for loop that prints out all the values of a dictionary. I've searched online for alternative ways to print these out without getting warned, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Here is the section of the program where the warning appears. It is at `for (key, value)`.

```
var dict = [String : [String]]()
dict["key1"] = ["Bruh", "Bruhh", "Bruhhh", "Bruhhhh"]
dict["key1"]!.append("!")
for (key,value) in dict
{
    print("\(value)")
}
print("\n")
```

I've seen code before with numerous warnings, but the programmers seem to be fine with them. Should I just ignore this issue?

Comment: "but the programmers seem to be fine with them." that's not good. Compiler/language writers don't just implement code warnings because they're just soooooo much fun to write.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Lol that makes sense. Are there any situations where it's fine to keep them?

Comment: I ignore warnings in dependencies like third party libraries. I'm not going to waste my time fixing them, only for me to make upgrading their versions harder in the future, and introducing the possibility for bugs. But otherwise, I like to treat warnings as errors. Bad code with no warnings is possible, but I don't believe that good code with warnings is possible (especially because they're usually such obvious things like using `let` when you're not mutating a `var`, for example

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Ah I see. So I guess that means I'll be fixing all of my warnings from now on, I was neglecting to do so before because I thought it was unnecessary. Thanks.

Comment: Well it's not necessary, that's what distinguishes warnings from errors. Programs with errors are incompilable, invalid Swift that the compiler can't salvage into a running program. Programs with warnings range from messy to making no sense at all, but the compiler is happy to give you rope to hang yourself. It's not "necessary" to fix them, but neither is it necessary to nicely indent code, write tests, profile performance, use good design/architecture. You're more than free to make a mess, but *you're* the one to pay the price of that, ultimately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not gonna use `key`, you can silence the warning be replacing `key` with `_`

So it'd look like this:

```swift
var dict = [String : [String]]()
dict["key1"] = ["Bruh", "Bruhh", "Bruhhh", "Bruhhhh"]
dict["key1"]!.append("!")
for (_, value) in dict
{
    print("\(value)")
}
print("\n")
```

This works in other places in Swift too:

```swift
func example() -> Int {
    return 1
}

let a = example() //Initialization of immutable value 'a' was never used
let _ = example() //No warning
```

Comment: Oh, I understand. So this warning only shows if you don't actually use `key` or `value`?

Comment: Exactly :) So what Xcode is saying is you defined this variable, `key`, but you never actually used it, making the definition of it useless. But the `_` tells the compiler that you're not gonna use it